# NextJS, two pages with Internationalized Routing

Tags: next.js, i18next

I have such page structure in my NextJS project:

```
/pages
│   index.js
│   [products].js
│   [services].js
```

Within [products] and [services], I'm using internalization for routing:

**[products].js:**

```
export const getStaticPaths = ({ locale }) => {
    return {
      paths: [
        { params: { products: 'gaminiai' }, locale: 'lt' },
        { params: { products: 'products' }, locale: 'en' },
      ],
      fallback: false,
    }
  }
```

**[services].js:**

```
export const getStaticPaths = ({ locale }) => {
    return {
      paths: [
        { params: { products: 'servisai' }, locale: 'lt' },
        { params: { products: 'services' }, locale: 'en' },
      ],
      fallback: false,
    }
  }
```

NextJs spits this error at me:

> You cannot use different slug names for the same dynamic path
> ('services' !== 'products').

Now, I understand that I can't have two slugs in same directory dynamically since NextJs doesn't know what slugs it'll get and it can end up being same slug for two different pages, however, is there a way around? I do give those slug names inside NextJS in advance, I don't get them from somewhere else.

Is there a way to use multiple pages with internalized paths in same directory? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to do a similar thing to this in my nextjs app.

Instead of creating multiple dynamic routes I created one catch all file ([...slug].js) and then set up a switch case to redirect the user to a specific react component.

I used an ACF field called 'contentType' and constructed the switch case based off of that.

[More details on dynamic routing from nextjs](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes)

[Specifically catch all routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes)

Comment: But is this SEO friendly? I mean, redirecting to a react component alone seems like a bad idea from SEO standpoint. Am I wrong?

Comment: @RTA If you're using ISR (Incremental Server-Side rendering) or SSG (Server-Side Generation it won't make a difference for seo because the the pages are generated on the server and your janky switch case does not need to be judged by seo. I have run tests to confirm this btw.